# What can a repeating stack trace mean?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, stack-trace, sqlexception

I have a webservice with a webmethod that is called asynchronously both at set intervals of time and randomly depending on different factors (which basically means it can be called at any time by multiple things). This webmethod calls a database several times within its body. I sometimes get timeouts, deadlocks and other indications of necessity of various improvements. This is not very relevant though. What I wanted to ask about is this stack trace:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at MyWebservice.PrivateMethod()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at MyWebservice.PrivateMethod()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at MyWebservice.PrivateMethod()
   at MyWebservice.WebMethod()
```

Things to note:

1. PrivateMethod is called only once within WebMethod, at its very beginning
2. There's no recursion involved
3. PrivateMethod is nothing more than calling a stored procedure and returning the result.
4. There's only one SqlConnection object used in PrivateMethod and only one SqlConnection.Open call.

This issue is not limited to PrivateMethod only, but does seem to be related to SqlConnection.Open. It also happens rarely and is a very small percentage of the timeout/deadlock problems I mentioned earlier - all of the other cases have normal looking stack traces.

Any ideas what could have caused a repeating stack trace? As I said, there's no recursion in the code there and there's no way my PrivateMethod is called from the inside of .NET library.

EDIT:
PrivateMethod looks like this:

```
using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP name here", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", _param);
    // several other parameters added the same way here

    SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter();
    result.ParameterName = "@result";
    result.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
    result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    command.Parameters.Add(result);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    try { _spresult = (bool)result.Value; }
    catch (InvalidCastException) { return true; }   // this is by design, please don't pester me about it

    return _spresult;
}
```

and it's called right at the very beginning of WebMethod if one of WebMethod's arguments is set to true, otherwise it's not called at all.

EDIT 2: Forgot to mention, it's .NET 2.0. No idea if it matters.

Comment: Can you post the method content and what calls it?

Comment: Which method? PrivateMethod is called at the very beginning of WebMethod and is nothing more than the standard - using SqlConnection, declare and define SqlCommand, add parameters, open connection, execute non query, return result. Is it really necessary to show the exact code?

Comment: It's probably more important to post what calls it. I can't think of anything to do with multi-threaded code that would cause weird stack traces like that, I would like to see the code to see if there is a subtle reason for it that you might be missing.

Comment: How do you get this stack trace? Is this what you see in exception details in debugger, or is this something you've read from any log?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth What calls the WebMethod? As far as I know it's a simple console application which is called for various sets of data and calls the WebMethod for every item in a set. I don't know how exactly that application is used though.

Comment: @Dennis WebMethod's whole body is contained within a try-catch block and if an exception is caught, an e-mail is sent with basically exception.ToString() as its content.

Comment: @S_F: could you post `catch` block code from `WebMethod`?

Comment: @S_F Unfortunately I have nothing more to add.

Comment: @Dennis Not the best idea, it would be quite long as it would be necessary to include the whole method for sending mails which is  a bit long to accomodate some functionalities not used in this case. What catch block does is using a StringBuilder to add the information about entry parameters and exception.ToString(). The mail sending method uses SmtpClient. There's also a finally block which tries to connect to the database again but that happens after logging the exception so it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: @S_F: looking at your stack trace and considering, that there is logging functionality, the first thing to think of is to search for errors in logging. Adam is right, `PrivateMethod` can't cause such stack trace (but logging code can). But if you don't want post any additional info, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your thread problems
Add static lockObj to the class

```
var isIdle = true;

if (isIdle)
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (isIdle)
                {
                  isIdle = false;
using SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
{
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SP name here", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramName", _param);
// several other parameters added the same way here

SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter();
result.ParameterName = "@result";
result.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
result.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(result);

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

try { _spresult = (bool)result.Value; }
catch (InvalidCastException) { return true; }   // this is by design, please don't pester me about it

}
                }
            }
        }
        return _spresult;
    }
```